# OpenCV - Reading a 16 bit grayscale image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to read a 16 bit grayscale image using OpenCV 2.4 in Python, but it seems to be loading it as 8 bit.

I'm doing:

```
im = cv2.imread(path,0)
print im

[[25 25 28 ...,  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
[ 0  0  0 ...,  0  0  0]
...,
```

How do I get it as 16 bit?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Figured it out. In case anyone else runs into this problem:

```
im = cv2.imread(path,-1)
```

Setting the flag to 0, to load as grayscale, seems to default to 8 bit. Setting the flag to -1 loads the image as is.

Comment: The flags works perfectly for me. It reads the image as `uint16` instead of `uint8`.

Comment: you should not use fixed numbers if there are approriate flags like `cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` (readability, maintainability, protection against changes in flag values)

Comment: for clarity, use `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` which equals -1.

Answer (score 39):

To improve readability use the flag **cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH**

```
image = cv2.imread( path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH )
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue (16-bit .tif loading as 8-bit using cv2.imread). However, using the -1 flag didn't help. Instead, I was able to load 16-bit images using the tifffile package.

Comment: The `tifffile` package worked perfectly.  Nothing I tried worked for `cv2.imread` flags: `cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH`, `cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR`, those two combined (`6`), as well as `-1`.

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622658/read-16-bit-png-image-file-using-python) suggests that `image = cv2.imread('16bit.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` will also solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing the other answers. The `-1` flag corresponds to the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag. You can check all flags available in the [imread modes documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.9.0/d8/d6a/group__imgcodecs__flags.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80aeddd67043ed0df14f9d9a4e66d2b0708) with its corresponding values at [the imread codes definition](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/18944261166ecf64568e17e374cecbf694a5672b/modules/imgcodecs/include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp#L68). **It is a good practice to use the flags instead of the values directly**, as other users pointed out, since the flags values are prone to changes.

Example from OpenCV 4.9.0 version.

```
   IMREAD_UNCHANGED = -1, // If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped). Ignore EXIF orientation.
   IMREAD_ANYDEPTH  = 2,  // If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.
```

So, to read your 16-bit grayscale image, the following flag could be enough:

```
image = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

But, `cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH` does not preserve the color channels as expected and if you are not sure if the image has color channels or is in fact 16-bit to further check after reading, is better to read with `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` as it tries to preserve the original image contents:

```
image = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```