# creating a 16 bit tiff image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, 16-bit

I am trying to create a 16-bit greyscale ring simulation and for some reason, it just does not work.

Let me explain, at the beginning, I wrote it in 8-bit format, and then I realized I need it in 16-bit. The code I wrote for the 8-bit format worked just fine and is presented below:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
from scipy.ndimage import convolve, gaussian_filter
import NumPy as np

def theta(x, y, phi):
    if np.angle(x - y*1j, deg=True) - phi > 180:
        return 1*(np.angle(x - y*1j, deg=True) - phi - 360)
    if np.angle(x - y*1j, deg=True) - phi < -180:
        return 1*(np.angle(x - y*1j, deg=True) - phi + 360)
    else:
        return np.angle(x - y*1j, deg=True) - phi


#  FWHM = 2.355*Sigma

# Simulation Parameters:
Intensity = 190  # Light intensity.

SIG = 1.666/2.355  # Sigma of radial Gaussian.

SIG1 = 45  # Sigma of first azimuthal Gaussian.
SIG2 = 25  # Sigma of second azimuthal Gaussian.
SIG3 = 10  # Sigma of third azimuthal Gaussian.

r0 = 8  # Radius of reference of radial Gaussian.
theta1 = 31  # Angle of reference of first azimuthal Gaussian.
theta2 = 157  # Angle of reference of second azimuthal Gaussian.
theta3 = -105  # Angle of reference of third azimuthal Gaussian.

# PSF Parameters:
Kernel = MakeGaussian(10, 1.666)  # Convolution kernel.

# Noise Parameters:
offset = 1  # Gaussian noise amplitude.
Ex = 10  # Gaussian noise expectation. (3*Var)
Var = 7  # Gaussian noise variance.

# Frame Parameters:
t = 1  # Number of frames.
w, h = 300, 300  # Frame size.

data = np.zeros((t, h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
noise = np.zeros((t, h, w), dtype=np.uint8)

for l in range(t):
    for i in range(w):
        for k in range(h):
            r = np.sqrt((i - w / 2) ** 2 + (k - h / 2) ** 2)
            data[l][i][k] = Intensity * np.exp(-((r - r0)**2)/(2*SIG**2)) * 1 * (np.exp(-((theta(k - w / 2, i - h / 2, theta1))**2)/(2*SIG1**2)) + np.exp(-((theta(k - w / 2, i - h / 2, theta2))**2)/(2*SIG2**2)) + np.exp(-((theta(k - w / 2, i - h / 2, theta3))**2)/(2*SIG3**2)) )
            noise[l][i][k] = offset * (1/np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * Var**2)) * np.random.normal(Ex, Var)

    pic = gaussian_filter(data[l], 1.666, 0) + noise[l]

    img = Image.fromarray(pic, 'L')
    img.save('%s.tiff' % l, format="tiff")
```

Now, when I am naively trying to make this code create 16-bit images by swapping to dtype='uint.16' it all goes to hell.

I would appreciate it if anyone can shed some light on what I should do to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4):

### Saving 16 bit unsigned image with PIL

In the code

```
img = Image.fromarray(pic, 'L')
```

The 'L' specifies 8-bit pixels, black and white according to the PIL documentation.

To create an unsinged int 16 bit image the 'I;16' option is required.

```
img = Image.fromarray(pic[0], 'I;16')
```

The stackoverflow post [Read 16-bit PNG image file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32622658/15531842) says there is issues with this argument, however it is working fine for me using PIL ver 8.2.0 and Python 3.8.8.

### other considerations

- You may also want to be careful with your data and noise array. They are unsigned 8 bit integers.

  ```
  data = np.zeros((t, h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
  noise = np.zeros((t, h, w), dtype=np.uint8)
  ```

  They can be converted to unsigned 16 using `np.uint16` as the dtype parameter.

  ```
  data = np.zeros((t, h, w), dtype=np.uint16)
  noise = np.zeros((t, h, w), dtype=np.uint16)
  ```
- Is it possible for your processing to create negative numbers? Another issue could be caused when placing negative numbers into an unsigned integer array.

Answer (score 1):

As [this blog post](https://www.tjelvarolsson.com/blog/saving-16bit-tiff-files-using-python/) suggests, you need help from an external library "libtiff". Since PIL struggles with 16-bit.

```
from libtiff import TIFF
tiff = TIFF.open('libtiff.tiff', mode='w')
tiff.write_image(ar)
tiff.close()
```